# Image Button not firing in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which I dynamically generate the bound fields. My first column in the gridview is an image while other three columns are dynamically generated.

**When I click on the image in my first column I want the 2nd columns value. How Can I get that ? Also, I am unable to fire event on clicking the image button.**

Aspx Code:

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <div style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 97.5vh">
                 <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
                       OnRowCommand="OnRowCommand" Width="500px">
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <img alt="" id="EditImage" style="cursor: pointer" height="24" width="24" src="images/plus.png" />
                             </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>                         
                     </Columns>
                 </asp:GridView>
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

cs File

```
// THIS DISPLAYS THE GRIDVIEW WITH 4 COLUMNS 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataTable dt = // Calling SP and displaying the results;

            // 3 COLUMNS: ID, NAME, TITLE
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                bfield.DataField = col.ColumnName;
                bfield.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
                gvCustomers.Columns.Add(bfield);
            }
            gvCustomers.DataSource = dt;
            gvCustomers.DataBind();
    }



protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
          //I THINK, NEED TO WRITE CODE HERE FOR CLICKING ON IMAGE BUTTON
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use image button:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgBtn" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ValueContainer") %>' ImageUrl="~/images/plus.png" />
```

on cs:

```
protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
          //I THINK, NEED TO WRITE CODE HERE FOR CLICKING ON IMAGE BUTTON

        var value = e.CommandArgument;
    }
```

pre render:

```
protected void OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach(GridViewRow row in gvCustomers.Rows) 
            {
                 var imgBtn = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("imgBtn");
                 imgBtn.CommandArgument = row.Cells[1].Text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What should I keep in the command argument ? My gridview is genereic where I generate randomly few columns, so I am using dynamic bound field.

Comment: Whatever column is holding the value that column name

Comment: Everytime that column name will be different, as it is a generic gridview.

Comment: use gridview pre render event then

Comment: What will that give, Can I write something like this:  **string id = gvCustomers.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;** in the prerender to get the column value of the 1st column ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the  to attempt to access values in the BoundField clolumns and if you declare the button in the aspx page as in your example code you can use the following as a column.

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" runat="server" CommandName="MyButton" ImageUrl="~/Images/Update.jpg" />
```

In the Code Behind.

```cs
protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //CommandArgument returns row index of clicked button
    int nCommandArg = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    return;
}
```